# where memory for extern variable will be stored and by which file

Tags: c++, extern

I read about extern variable, but no where found answer related to its memory allocation, My question is Who will allocate memory for Extern variable, and in which memory segment.

```
int a; // file 1

extern int a; // file 2
```

here file 1 will allocate memory for a or file 2. In data segment or in stack ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **The extern keyword means "declare without defining".** In other words, it is a way to explicitly declare a variable, or to force a declaration without a definition.

So in `file2`, you just declared the variable without definition (no memory allocated). In `file1`, you declared and defined a variable of type `integer`. Here you allocated memory on the [BSS segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) because you have an *uninitialized global* (for C).

In C++, the globals are stored in a **per-process data area**.

---

Difference between declaration and definition :

> To understand how external variables relate to the extern keyword, it is necessary to know the difference between defining and declaring a variable.
>
> When a variable is defined, the compiler allocates memory for that variable and possibly also initializes its contents to some value. When a variable is declared, the compiler requires that the variable be defined elsewhere.
>
> The declaration informs the compiler that a variable by that name and type exists, but the compiler need not allocate memory for it since it is allocated elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thanks for clearing doubt. But as in file 1, var 'a' is global and it stores memory into data segment, so it will be in data segment or as you mentioned in stack ? I am not clear with this. can you explain please.

Comment: In your case it is in the [BSS segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) because it is an initialized global variable.

Comment: There is no such thing as a BSS segment in standard C++.

Comment: @robson3.14 I don't know why I'm still thinking in C... I fixed it. Thanks for pointing this out ;)

Answer (score 5):

In **file 2** an integer type variable called `a` has been declared (remember no definition i.e. no memory allocation for `a` so far). And we can do this declaration as many times as needed.
Where is in **file 1** an integer type variable called `a` has been declared as well as defined. (remember that definition is the super set of declaration). Here the memory for `a` is also allocated.

Comment: Thanks @hitesh, can you please tell me in which memory segment memory will be allocated ? will it be in Data segment as it will be global for file 1 ? And if we are not including file 1 in file 2 , like #include <file1.h> then will it give any error ?

Comment: That will throws error in compilation. Because var is declared but not defined anywhere. If you want to work that fine without including `file1.h` than make you extern variable like `extern int a = 0;`